# How to enable voice chat in Kopete chat client?

Tags: kopete

Hhow do I enable voice chat in Kopete chat client? I am using Kopete for Yahoo! and Gmail, please help me to enable voice chat for the Yahoo! account.

Answer (score 1):

**Kopete configuration  Facebook**

1. Click “Settings” in the top menu and then click “Configure”.

   2. Under “Accounts”, click “Add Account…”
   3. Select “Jaber” from the list of protocol choices.
   4. For username, type your Facebook  name (what is normally at the end of your Facebook URL)  For example, if your Facebook name is bobblehead, you will need to enter bobblehead@chat.facebook.com If, for some reason, that username does not work, you can check the [Facebook Chat](http://www.facebook.com/sitetour/chat.php) page in their site tour, click “Other – Windows/Mac/Linux” and see what your username is supposed to be.
   5. Password is your normal Facebook password.
   6. Under Connection preferences, leave all three options unchecked (no SSL).
   7. Click OK, and you’re done!

**Kopete configuration  Google Talk**

1. From the main Kopete window, click Settings > Configure....

[image]

2. Select Accounts from the left nav bar and click New....
3. From the list of available services, select Jabber and click Next.
4. Click the Basic Setup tab and enter the following information:

   ```
     * Jabber ID:
           o If you're signing in with a Gmail or Google Mail username, enter your full email address.
           o If your Google Talk username isn't associated with any Google email product, add @gmail.com to the end of your username. For example, iloveyoko will become iloveyoko@gmail.com.
           o If you're a Google Apps user, enter your full email address (gordon@example.com).

     * Remember password: Check this box if you'd like Kopete to remember your password.
     * Password: If you chose to Remember password, enter your Google Talk password.
     * Exclude from connect all: Check this box if you'd like to exclude this connection when Kopete connects to all configured services.
   ```
5. Click the Connection tab and enter the following information:
         * Check the Use protocol encryption (SSL), Allow plain-text password authentication, and Override default server information boxes.
         * Enter talk.google.com in the Server field.
         * Enter 5223 as the Port value.

[image]

6. Click Next.
7. Check Connect now to connect to Google Talk.
8. Click Finish.